# Лаги при прокрутке ListView (смена цвета фона строки)

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть код в Адаптере, который парсит доминантный цвет каждой картинки в ListView и ставит этот цвет на фон каждой ячейки.

```
Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(currentNews.getmImg())).into(holder.img, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)holder.img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
                holder.mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(p.getDominantColor(0));
                holder.img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {

            }
        });
```

Все прекрасно работает, за исключением одного - прокрутка списка сильно лагает. При появлении на экране новой строки, я вижу, как меняется цвет фона.

Можно ли как-то менять этот цвет даже в то время, когда строки не видны еще на экране?

Comment: используете ли вы при заполнении ListView паттерн ViewHolder?

Comment: Да, использую. Не помогает

Comment: ну что еще приходит на ум.. попробовать в логике приложения получать цвета заранее и попробовать перейти на RecyclerView

Comment: Заранее никак - картинка грузится по ссылке, спарсенной через Jsoup.

Comment: Забыл сказать. Лагает именно на эмуляторе. Но моем телефоне все ок, но он у меня мощный. На более слабых проверить возможности нет.

Comment: в таком случае может быть проблема связанная с самой эмуляцией